# Python path in environment

Tags: python, windows, scripting, development-environment, environment-variables

I want to call a python script from batch script, but I dont want to hard-code path to python executable (python.exe) in my calling script.

e.g.

```
c:\python26\python.exe test.py

$PYTHONPATH\python.exe test.py
```

Is there any way to have PYTHONPATH like setting ?

Comment: why don't you just call it `test.py`. or it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @SilentGhost The question should have been rather *Why don't you call `python test.py`?* as this is the usual way to call Python script on Windows. Counting on right association of Python files is much more fragile.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing is to add c:\python26 to you system's PATH.

Also, depending on how you installed Python, you should be able to just use test.py on the command line.

Comment: Doesn't python installation do any such setting? Because I will not know on which setup will my script run.

Comment: Some Python installers do, but I don't know if you can count on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
set PYTHON_INSTALL=D:\python26
```

then:

```
%PYTHON_INSTALL%\python.exe test.py
```

You could set up the PYTHON_INSTALL var using My Computer | Advanced | Environment Variables if you want it to persist.

EDIT:
And building on the other post (put the path to Python in the system path), you could have the best of both worlds:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_INSTALL%
```

Then you can just call:

```
python test.py
```

EDIT 2:

Renamed 'PYTHONPATH' to 'PYTHON_INSTALL' as another poster pointed out that the environment variable 'PYTHONPATH' already has a defined use.

Comment: Don't use PYTHONPATH for this, as it already serves a different purpose (telling Python about extra directories to add to its module search path.)

Comment: And I think 'set PATH' should use ';' as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\python26
%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe test.py
```

Or

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\python26;
python test.py
```

**Note**: environment variable **PYTHONPATH** has different purpose for searching python modules/extensions, So should not be shadowed.

```
PYTHONPATH   : ';'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
               default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
```